# how to find users location when a photo is taken and display+save in a UIMapView

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, location, mkmapview

was just wondering how i would basically go about finding the user's location and then displaying this in an un-editable UImapView. This would be used to location stamp photos and videos taken within the app and must still be displayed whilst the app is open.Just as a disclaimer i am not asking anyone to sit and write this code for me (but feel free to if you want) i was just hoping that someone else may have already done this and so might provide their code as a reference. thanks for any help you can provide

Comment: You should probably divide this question into separate (more or less atomic) tasks. I'm sure you already know how to do a certain percentage of those. Then just post separate questions about the tasks you are having problems with. Just saying... For example if you are reading photos/videos from the library some might come with location data & some without. If you're taking them from within the app you have to take care that `CLLocationManager` is up and running.

Answer (score 0):

As rokjarc says, you need to break this into pieces.

The camera app that's built into iOS already has the option to save location data into your photos.

Are you saying that you want to be able embed location information in pictures that you take from within your app?

You have at least 3 different things you need to read about:

CLLocationManager. You would create an instance of the location manager and ask it to start updating your location. It takes a while to settle down, so you would want to start it when your app is launched. You'll want to fine-tune the settings so it only notifies you on fairly large location changes to conserve battery. The location manager is an async library, so you start it updating, then wait for it to notify you, and parse the location updates it gives you to make sure they are current/accurate enough.

Next, map kit. You would need to add an MKMapView to your app's views, and set it up to display to a window. you could either use the option that shows the user's location automatically, or use location manager information to change the map region and/or create a map annotation showing the user's current location.

Third, you will need to figure out how to save location metadata to the images you take. That's not something I've done, so I don't have any specific help for you.